# Need a Unique ID to be populated in Google sheets on Google Form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

Looking for a dynamic unique ID for Google Forms, to populate into Google Sheets Response form. I don't want to use external addons.

Below is a code I found online but can't get it to work - I'm a beginner to app script. So maybe I'm missing something.
The problem seems to be with the "slice" (however that's more of a guess).

- The script was connected to the Google response sheet.
- The trigger was added (to the google sheet) on OnFormSumbit
- No errors occurred with the trigger, when I submitted the form (checked the log afterwards).
- However no unique ID were presented on the response sheet either.
- I'm guessing from my limited experience that the **slice** function seems to be a problem

*Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.*

Ultimately I want to create a form, which when populated gives me a unique JobCard number which is populated in my google sheet Reponses.
Something with a set number of Characters (say 6) with a prefix (say JBC) and if this could be in numerical order that would be create but not a deal breaker.

**I found the below code however it doesn't seem to work:**

```
/**
* This function extracts the relevant properties from the event handler,
* then uses them to get the uniqueID and record the response
* @param {Object} e The event parameter for form submission to a spreadsheet;
*     e has the following properties values, range, namedValues
*/

function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var uniqueID = getUniqueID(e.values);
  recordResponseID(e.range, uniqueID);
}

/**
* Records the unique ID for this response to the correct cell.
* @param  {Object} eventRange Range in which the response is written
* @param  {Integer} uniqueID   Unique id for this range
*/

function recordResponseID(eventRange, uniqueID) {
  var row = eventRange.getRow();
  var column = eventRange.getLastColumn() + 1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(row, column).setValue(uniqueID);

}
/**
* A shortcut function to get the form that is connected to this spreadsheet
* @return {Form}          The form associated with this spreadsheet.
**/

function getConnectedForm() {
  var formUrl = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl();
  var form =  FormApp.openByUrl(formUrl);
  return form;
}

/**
* Returns a unique ID for the response, by finding the actual Response that
* has the same properties.
* @param  {Array} eventValues Array of: Timestamp_string, form_response_value...
* @return {Integer}             The unique id (by 1 based array position) of the Response
*/

function getUniqueID(eventValues) {
  var isMatch = false;
  var eventItems = eventValues.slice(1);

  var responses = getConnectedForm().getResponses();
  //loop backwards through responses (latest is most likely)
  for (var i = responses.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    var responseItems = responses[i].getItemResponses();
    //check each value matches

    for (var j = 0; j < responseItems.length; j++) {
      if (responseItems[j].getResponse() !== eventItems[j]) {
        break;
      }
      isMatch = true;
    }
    if (isMatch) {
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
}

function testOnSubmit() {
  var answers = [
    ["Sue", "39", "Okay I suppose"],
    ["John", "22", "Great"],
    ["Jane", "45", "yeah no"],
    ["Bob", "33", "Super"]
  ];

  var form = getConnectedForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    var formResponse = form.createResponse();
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      var item = items[j];
      var itemResponse = item.asTextItem().createResponse(answers[i][j]);
      formResponse.withItemResponse(itemResponse);
    }
    formResponse.submit();
    Utilities.sleep(500);
  }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you never delete any form responses, you can use this formula in row 1 of a free column in the form responses sheet:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    row(A1:A) = 1, "Unique ID", 
    isblank(A1:A), iferror(1/0), 
    true, "JBC" & text(row(A1:A) - 1, "000000") 
  ) 
)
```

If you need to be able to delete rows from the form responses sheet, use the code below. Create an [installable "on form submit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) on the *spreadsheet* to make it run automatically when new responses are submitted.

```
/**
* Inserts a unique ID after the last column of the form response sheet
* when a new form response is submitted.
*
* @param {Object} e The "on form submit" event object.
*/
function insertUniqueIdOnFormSubmit(e) {
  // version 1.2, written by --Hyde, 6 June 2022
  //  - see https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/164893/269219
  if (!e || !e.range) {
    return
  };
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();

  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  const sheetsToWatch = /^(Form Responses 1)$/i;
  const uniqueIdCell = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, e.range.columnEnd + 1);
  const _formatNumber = (number) => 'JBC' + right_('000000' + String(number), 6);
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////

  if (!sheet.getName().match(sheetsToWatch)) {
    return;
  }
  const uniqueIdRange = sheet.getRange(1, uniqueIdCell.getColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  const existingUniqueIds = uniqueIdRange.getValues().flat();
  const newId = getUniqueId_(existingUniqueIds, _formatNumber);
  uniqueIdCell.setValue(newId);
}


/**
* Gets a unique ID.
*
* @param {String[]} existingUniqueIds The existing IDs to check to verify that the new ID is unique.
* @param {Function} formatNumber A function to format the number.
* @return {String|Number} A unique ID.
*/
function getUniqueId_(existingUniqueIds, formatNumber) {
  let number = 1;
  let id;
  do {
    id = formatNumber(number++);
  } while (existingUniqueIds.indexOf(id) !== -1);
  return id;
}


/**
* Extracts characters from the end of a text string.
*
* @param {String} text The text string where to extract rightmost characters.
* @param {Number} numCharacters The number of characters to extract.
* @return {String} The extracted characters.
*/
function right_(text, numCharacters) {
  return text.slice(-numCharacters);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, However I'll be using this unique ID for a lookup for multiple other things - which is why I'm trying to make it bullet proof.

Comment: Added Apps Script code to do the same.

Comment: Just tested the code. It seem replaces all the responses in the sheet as well as adds a last column. Kindly see if you could correct it - otherwise it works well.

Comment: Just tested the code. It replaces all the responses in the sheet, as well as adds a last column, all with the reference value. Kindly see if you could correct it - otherwise it works perfectly - thank you.

Comment: Edited the code. Please try again.